# How to disable buttons until another button is clicked in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, button, angular-forms, angularjs-ng-disabled

**Actually I am stuck in this thing .**

**What I want to do is that I have 3 buttons in my Component.html file in angular and what I need is that when I load the page only the button (Get Bank Details) should be enabled and the other two should be disabled then after I click the (Get Bank Details) button it should become disable now and the next button (See Bank Details) should be enable now leaving the other 2 buttons disabled and the when I click on (See Bank Details) button the 3rd button (Go to Update Bank) should now become enabled and the rest 2 diasabled.**

**If I explain in an easy manner**

```
on Page Load :  1 Button - enabled , 2 Button - disabled , 3 Button - disabled
After 1 Button clicked : 1 Button - disabled , 2 Button - enabled , 3 Button - disabled
After 2 Button clicked : 1 Button - disabled , 2 Button - disabled , 3 Button - enabled
```

** This is the HTML code**

```
 <div style="width: 2000px; padding: auto;">
                            
                            <button id="button1" class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" >Get Bank Details</button> | 
                            <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" (click)="getBankById()" >See Bank Details</button> |
                            <button  class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" (click)="router.navigate(['/home/patchBank']);">Go to Update Bank</button>
                        
                        </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? What have you tried to accomplish the expected result?

Comment: Actually I have no idea , like how to approach this ,  I know how to disable buttons in angular in case of form handling but I am not able to get an approach of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two boolean flags to check which button should be enabled and disabled and then use the `[disabled]` attribute to conditionally enable or disable the button. A small example would look like this:

```js
seeBankDetailFlag: boolean;
goToUpdateBankFlag: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void{
     this.seeBankDetailFlag = true;
     this.goToUpdateBankFlag = true;
  }

  getBankDetails(): void{
     this.seeBankDetailFlag = false;
  }

  getBankById(): void{
       this.seeBankDetailFlag = true;
       this.goToUpdateBankFlag = false;
  }
```

and then in your HTML you bind the flags with `[disabled]`

```html
 <div style="width: 2000px; padding: auto;">
     <button id="button1" class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" (click)="getBankDetails()" 
     [disabled]="!seeBankDetailFlag || !goToUpdateBankFlag">
        Get Bank Details
     </button>
     <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" (click)="getBankById()" 
     [disabled]="seeBankDetailFlag">
         See Bank Details
     </button>
     <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" (click)="router.navigate(['/home/patchBank']);" 
     [disabled]="goToUpdateBankFlag">
         Go to Update Bank
     </button>
 </div>
```

A simple stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hdcbk

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I can think of is just to have a boolean for each button

```
disableGetBankDetails = false;
seeBankDetails = true;

<button id="button1" [disabled]=[disableGetBankDetails] (click)="getBankDetails()" type="submit" >Get Bank Details</button>

<button [disabled]=[seeBankDetails]>See Bank Details</button>
```

When you click on the get bank details button, you change the values to what you need.

```
getBankDetails() {
    this.disableGetBankDetails = true;
    this.seeBankDetails = false;
}
```